# java regex for any word

Tags: java, regex

im trying to figure out the regex to use to split an essay into words WITHOUT punctuation.  I tried splitting by whitespace, but that gives some tokens with the punctuation.  I also tried to split by word chars, which returned an array of empty strings for some reason:

```
String[] words = line.split("\\w+");
```

Comment: [Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) the summary of regular expressions constructs. Build your `split` regex from the appropriate constructs.

Comment: i read that, since i want to match words, i want to use one or more word characters([a-zA-Z0-9]).  once it encounters non word chars it wont match anymore, so I thought that was the regex I needed.  I dont see what is wrong with my reasoning for choosing this regex

Comment: In @SotiriosDelimanolis' link to reg ex constructs look for word boundary \b. Then please delete this post. There are answers to this question all over the internet including SO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java regular expression word match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165689/java-regular-expression-word-match)

Comment: You should also read the javadoc of `split`.

Comment: i shouldnt need word boundary if I am using word chars

Comment: Your issues sound odd. Please provide some example input that gives you these results. Looking at a single line of code we can only guess at the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
String[] words = line.split("\\W+");
```

Comment: funny.  I knew about \W in the back of my head and thought to use \s+ first, then got confused and messed up the definition of split and used \w+, and didn't realize to use the opposite of that.