# Java extracting specific characters from random string

Tags: java

I am a newbie I have a program that randomly gives me a string.

My task is to extract and display specific characters from this string.

Ex :

```
String s = "condor:4,2:d\nocelot:12,12:h\nvocabulary:12,12:g\nwilderness:1,3:b";
```

display :

```
condor, ocelot, vocabulary, wilderness
```

I can only use Class String and System.No tokenizer, no table [], no ArrayList().

Comment: You need to become familiar with Java documentation for their classes. See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html) to get started. Look up the String class on the left hand side and then look through the various methods to see which ones might be useful for this task.

Comment: you can use regex(Regular Expression) for this purpose. check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165689/java-regular-expression-word-match)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What exactly was the problem?

Comment: No regex either !!!

Comment: I tried doing this : affichelisteMots = affichelisteMots.replace("\n", ", ");
 It deleted me the \n. After this i dont know what to do next.

Comment: Before coding, start by explaining the task to someone else on a whiteboard. Then, maybe you can get away with `String.split` as in `s.split("\n")` (ask) and also use `String.indexOf`, `String.substring` and `String.join`.

Answer (score -2):

Use this code for solve your problem:
In a for loop iterate char by char the string and check that character ascii code is in range of letter and in this condition block if answer is true add the charecter to temp that in first is empty and if answer is false and if temp is not empty and is not just a letter print temp. the last if for the string finish by last character of word that came out of loop

```
    int a;
    String temp = "";
    String nodes = "condor:4,2:d\nocelot:12,12:h\nvocabulary:12,12:g\nwilderness:1,3:b";

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length(); i++) {
        a = (int) nodes.charAt(i);
        if ((a >= 97 && a <= 122) || (a >= 65 && a <= 90)) {
            temp = temp + nodes.charAt(i);
        } else if (temp != "" && temp.length() != 1) {
            System.out.println(temp);
            temp = "";
        }else if(temp != "" && temp.length() == 1){
            temp = "";
        }
    }
    if (temp != "" && temp.length() != 1)
        System.out.println(temp);
```

Comment: Can you add explanation? Code only often is not that useful, especially for beginner questions.

Comment: In a for loop iterate char by char the string and check that character ascii code is in range of letter and in this condition block if answer is true add the charecter to temp that in first is empty and if answer is false and if temp is not empty and is not just a letter print temp.
the last if for the string finish by last character of word that came out of loop.

Comment: Please include the explanation inside your answer by **editing** it, thanks.

Comment: So you can use stringJoiner.add(temp); instead of System.out.println(temp); and at last System.out.println(stringJoiner); of course at first you should make an instance from it : StringJoiner stringJoiner=new StringJoiner(",");

Comment: Using integer literals (97, etc) instead of char literals ('a') makes the code harder to read. On the other hand, Java uses the Unicode character set, so `Character.isLetter(nodes.charAt(i))` wouldn't make assumptions about the letters in the data.